# Videos not starting inside my window application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am experiencing the following issue: Videos do not load in my window form. I also inserted buttons to have the function start and play, but nothing happened. My template before running is seeing the videos, but when the window form starts, then on the place of the video is nothing.

Here is my code:

```
        <MediaElement Name="CheckFWmonitor" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Height="200" Margin="719,107,0,0" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="366"
                      Source="C:\crask\videos\FWMon.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="719,307,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321">
            <Label Name="lblStatus" Content="Not playing..." HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5" />
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Name="btnPlay" Click="BtnPlay_Click">Play</Button>
                <Button Name="btnPause" Margin="5,0" Click="BtnPause_Click">Pause</Button>
                <Button Name="btnStop" Click="BtnStop_Click">Stop</Button>
            </WrapPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

And this is my cs code:

```
public Notregistered()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Yes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            notregisteredsteps.yes21 yes21next = new notregisteredsteps.yes21();
            this.Hide();
            yes21next.ShowDialog();
        }
        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckFWlocaly.Source != null)
            {
                if (CheckFWlocaly.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
                    lblStatus.Content = String.Format("{0} / {1}", CheckFWlocaly.Position.ToString(@"mm\:ss"), CheckFWlocaly.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
            }
            else
                lblStatus.Content = "No file selected...";
        }

        private void BtnPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckFWlocaly.Play();
        }

        private void BtnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckFWlocaly.Pause();
        }

        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckFWlocaly.Stop();
        }
```

I am also experiencing a side issue that is also connected to this. When I try to load a file from the directory of the project - if it is not a specifically set destination, it gives me an error: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified'"

```
var localTools = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}tools/facebook.rdp";
Process.Start(localTools);
```

and when I try to debug it, shows me this location: "Project/Bin/Debug/(searches the file from this folder). Same is if I move the file to the directory without a folder and try to launch it there.

Thank in advance ! :)

Comment: when combining paths, use `Path.Combine` its more robust also its good to get your back slashes the right way around

Answer (score 0):

I create a project with your codes and it worked properly for me.

> var localTools = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}tools/facebook.rdp";

Use \ instead of / in file path;